# How to json encode a database model in php?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, json

I'm building a restful web service with php. I want to implement subscription/subscribers in which both of them are user entities.

I have a database model as follow:

```
subscription table/model:

id,
subscriber_id,
publisher_id

user table/model:

id,
firstname,
lastname
```

I want to get the $id for a user as a get request and return the following json response for subscribers list in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "id" : "USER_SUBSCRIPTION_ID",
        "subscriber" : {
            "id" : "subscriber1",
            "firstname" : "subscriber1_fname",
            "lastname" : "subscriber1_lname",
        },
        "publisher" : {
            "id" : "requester_id",
            "firstname" : "requester_fname",
            "lastname" : "requester_lname",
        }
    },
    {
        "id" : "USER_SUBSCRIPTION_ID",
        "subscriber" : {
            "id" : "subscriber1",
            "firstname" : "subscriber2",
            "lastname" : "subscriber2",
        },
        "publisher" : {
            "id" : "requester_id",
            "firstname" : "requester_fname",
            "lastname" : "requester_lname",
        }
    }
]
```

I also wrote a serializer which gets my database model and encode it to json. I don't know how to use it in this situation though because I can not replace both publisher_id and subscriber_id with their corresponding record in user table. 
What is the easiest and cleanest way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a framework for your application such as [Zend](http://www.zend.com), [Phalcon PHP](http://www.phalconphp.com) or similar, the best practice for returning such data would be like this:

1. Your models should have any sensitive properties `private` or `protected`. This is what's called [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). In your case, there doesn't seem to be any, but it's important to remember.
2. When the model is retrieved from the server, you can just do `json_encode` on it, and it will generated the content you've supplied as example, leaving out any non-visible properties.

The above is applicable if you're using objects w/o frameworks as well.

If you're not using OOP, I suggest you do. This will allow PHP to do the work for you, even if it's "just" a RESTful service, since it can type-juggle with objects representing the data.

Finally, if you're not going OOP on this, there's no safe type-juggling available; you'll have to structure your data manually before JSON encoding it.

**EDIT**

Worth mentioning is that if you're using a framwork, there are often export methods available for formatting your output, such as the `toArray()` methods on Phalcon PHP DB results.

Also, if you're using vanilla `PDO` for the DB connection, you can `json_encode()` a `$statement` straight up.

Comment: @Helge-talvik-soderstorm Thanks for you answer, I'm not using any framework, I'm using OOP though and I have encapsulation.
I want to know how to do the sql query so that I can get my subscription model in which publisher_id and subscriber_id are replaced with their corresponding user record.
if I do the join user.id = subscription.publisher_id it will only points to publisher record. is there a way to do the join so that I can get the both columns record?

Comment: Aha, allright. I may have misunderstood your question. If you want to do this with SQL, you'd have to join the user table twice. Here's a select for you:

`select s.id as "Relation ID", su.id as "Subscriber User ID", su.firstname as "Subscriber firstname", su.lastname as "Subscriber lastname", pu.id as "Publisher User ID", pu.firstname as "Publisher firstname", pu.lastname as "Publisher lastname" from subscription as s join user as su on s.subscriber_id = su.id join user as pu on s.publisher_id = pu.id;`

Did I understand you correctly? If so, I'd like to write a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks that's close to what I need, but I need to get the exact output format as above!